# itextsharp: setting dimensions of image manually

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, itext

the user will pick an image on their hardrive and i will put it on a pdf file using itextsharp with vb.net. how do i manually set the dimensions of the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article provides a simple example](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_resize.html) of resizing a System.Drawing.Image using VB.NET. It gets the Image from a PictureBox control on the Windows Form, but you can acquire the Image from another source; possibly making it a parameter in the function.